# Series of a subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence, such that $ \Sigma x_n $ converges. Does  $ \Sigma x_{n_k}$ Converge in all cases? $(x_{n_k})$ is. Subsequence of  $(x_n)$

Answer (score 1):

No.  Consider the alternating sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty {(-1)^i\over i}$$

Then the even terms and odd terms diverge in sum, but the whole sum converges.  This is a major difference between absolutely convergent sums and conditionally convergent sums.

Comment: you were faster :) +1

Comment: Thanks. :-)  Finally saw an easy one that I could type the answer to quickly.  I was lucky that my $i=0$ didn't get logged in the edit history...

Comment: @abiessu are you suggest that the statement is true for absolute converging sums?

Comment: @user97840: I believe that this would be one way to define absolutely converging sums vs. conditionally converging sums, whether there exists a subsequence such that the sum over the subsequence diverges.  If it can be shown that the sum of every subsequence converges, then the sum over the sequence is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $(x_n) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and consider either the subsequence of even terms or odd terms.